# How to open the text file on the same frame when it runs first time?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mixing

I have made a small notepad demo and I am trying to open the file in same frame in the main frame but while opening the file it opens in different frame, I want it open in the first frame that opens when I run the program.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

  public class DemoMenu extends Frame 
   {
     Frame frm=new Frame();
     MenuBar bar=new MenuBar();
     //frm.setMenuBar(bar);
     Menu mf=new Menu("File");
     Menu me=new Menu("Edit");
     Menu mfo=new Menu("Format");
     Menu mv=new Menu("View");
     Menu mh=new Menu("Help");

     MenuItem mf1=new MenuItem("New"+"     "+"Ctrl+N");
     MenuItem mf2=new MenuItem("Open..."+"     "+"Ctrl+O");
     MenuItem mf3=new MenuItem("Save"+"     "+"Ctrl+S");
     MenuItem mf4=new MenuItem("Save As...");
     MenuItem mf5=new MenuItem("Page Setup...");
     MenuItem mf6=new MenuItem("Print..."+"     "+"Ctrl+P");
     MenuItem mf7=new MenuItem("Exit");

    MenuItem me1=new MenuItem("Undo"+"     "+"Ctrl+Z");
    MenuItem me2=new MenuItem("Cut"+"     "+"Ctrl+X");
    MenuItem me3=new MenuItem("Copy"+"     "+"Ctrl+C");
    MenuItem me4=new MenuItem("Paste"+"     "+"Ctrl+V");
    MenuItem me5=new MenuItem("Delete"+"     "+"Del" );
    MenuItem me6=new MenuItem("Find..."+"     "+"Ctrl+F");
    MenuItem me7=new MenuItem("Find Next"+"     "+"F3");
    MenuItem me8=new MenuItem("Replace..."+"     "+"Ctrl+H");
    MenuItem me9=new MenuItem("Go To"+"     "+"Ctrl+G");
    MenuItem me10=new MenuItem("Select All"+"     "+"Ctrl+A");
    MenuItem me11=new MenuItem("Date/Time"+"     "+"F5");

    MenuItem mfo1=new MenuItem("Word Wrap");
    MenuItem mfo2=new MenuItem("Font...");

    MenuItem mv1=new MenuItem("Status Bar");

    MenuItem mh1=new MenuItem("Help Topics");
    MenuItem mh2=new MenuItem("About Notepad");

   public static void main(String args[])
    {
     DemoMenu dm=new DemoMenu();

    }
  public DemoMenu()
    {
        super("United- Notepad");
        setMenuBar(bar);
        bar.add(mf);
        bar.add(me);
        bar.add(mfo);
        bar.add(mv);
        bar.add(mh);

        mf.add(mf1);
        mf.add(mf2);
        mf.add(mf3);
        mf.add(mf4);
        mf.addSeparator();
        mf.add(mf5);
        mf.add(mf6);
        mf.addSeparator();
        mf.add(mf7);

      mf1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane smd=new JOptionPane();
            smd.showMessageDialog(null,"Press Ok to open new page");
        }
    });

      final JTextArea jta=new JTextArea(10,20);
      JScrollPane scrl=new JScrollPane(jta);
     frm.add(scrl);

        mf2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
         int selection=chooser.showOpenDialog(frm);
          if(selection==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"so u want to open the file...");
       frm.setSize(520,540);
       frm.setVisible(true);

       File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

       FileInputStream fis=null;

      try
           {
            fis=new FileInputStream(file);
            byte b[]=new byte[fis.available()]; 
            fis.read(b);
            String str=new String(b);
            jta.setText(str);
            }
          catch(Exception f)
           {
                f.printStackTrace();
           }
               }
        }
    });

       mf3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        }

    });


        mf4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showDialog(null,"Save As");
        }
    });

            mf7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane scd=new JOptionPane();
            scd.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you want to exit");
        }
    });
             me.add(me1);
             me.addSeparator();
             me.add(me2);
             me.add(me3);
             me.add(me4);
             me.add(me5);
             me.addSeparator();
             me.add(me6);
             me.add(me7);
             me.add(me8);
             me.add(me9);
             me.addSeparator();
             me.add(me10);
             me.add(me11);
            me11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             Date d1=new Date();
            JOptionPane smddate=new JOptionPane();
            smddate.showMessageDialog(null,d1);
        }
    });

          mfo.add(mfo1);
          mfo.add(mfo2);

          mv.add(mv1);

          mh.add(mh1);
          mh.addSeparator();
          mh.add(mh2);

          setSize(520,540);
          setVisible(true);
   }
      }
```

Comment: 1) This code uses a strange mix of AWT (e.g. `Frame`) & Swing (e.g. `JOptionPane`).  It would be best to keep it all Swing. 2) One blank line of white space is always enough! 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I see over 20 menu items there, whereas I suspect it only needs 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, lets start here...

```
public class DemoMenu extends Frame 
{
    Frame frm=new Frame();
```

You extend `Frame` but then you create another reference to another `Frame` as well.

Instead of using `DemoMenu`, you seem to be using this "other" `frm` instead...

You're also mixing heavy and lightweight components (AWT/Swing), this is never going to end well.  Instead of

- `Frame`, use `JFrame`
- `Menu`, use `JMenu`
- `MenuItem`, use `JMenuItem`

Which lets me introduce you to `setDefaultCloseOperation` which will allow you to define what action should take place when the use tries to close window via the "x" button...

If you open a stream, you are responsible for closing it (see you file open method).

This should make your code look more like...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DemoMenu extends JFrame {

//    Frame frm = new Frame();
    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    //frm.setJMenuBar(bar);
    JMenu mf = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu me = new JMenu("Edit");
    JMenu mfo = new JMenu("Format");
    JMenu mv = new JMenu("View");
    JMenu mh = new JMenu("Help");
    JMenuItem mf1 = new JMenuItem("New" + "     " + "Ctrl+N");
    JMenuItem mf2 = new JMenuItem("Open..." + "     " + "Ctrl+O");
    JMenuItem mf3 = new JMenuItem("Save" + "     " + "Ctrl+S");
    JMenuItem mf4 = new JMenuItem("Save As...");
    JMenuItem mf5 = new JMenuItem("Page Setup...");
    JMenuItem mf6 = new JMenuItem("Print..." + "     " + "Ctrl+P");
    JMenuItem mf7 = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    JMenuItem me1 = new JMenuItem("Undo" + "     " + "Ctrl+Z");
    JMenuItem me2 = new JMenuItem("Cut" + "     " + "Ctrl+X");
    JMenuItem me3 = new JMenuItem("Copy" + "     " + "Ctrl+C");
    JMenuItem me4 = new JMenuItem("Paste" + "     " + "Ctrl+V");
    JMenuItem me5 = new JMenuItem("Delete" + "     " + "Del");
    JMenuItem me6 = new JMenuItem("Find..." + "     " + "Ctrl+F");
    JMenuItem me7 = new JMenuItem("Find Next" + "     " + "F3");
    JMenuItem me8 = new JMenuItem("Replace..." + "     " + "Ctrl+H");
    JMenuItem me9 = new JMenuItem("Go To" + "     " + "Ctrl+G");
    JMenuItem me10 = new JMenuItem("Select All" + "     " + "Ctrl+A");
    JMenuItem me11 = new JMenuItem("Date/Time" + "     " + "F5");
    JMenuItem mfo1 = new JMenuItem("Word Wrap");
    JMenuItem mfo2 = new JMenuItem("Font...");
    JMenuItem mv1 = new JMenuItem("Status Bar");
    JMenuItem mh1 = new JMenuItem("Help Topics");
    JMenuItem mh2 = new JMenuItem("About Notepad");

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                DemoMenu dm = new DemoMenu();
            }
        });

    }

    public DemoMenu() {
        super("United- Notepad");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setJMenuBar(bar);
        bar.add(mf);
        bar.add(me);
        bar.add(mfo);
        bar.add(mv);
        bar.add(mh);

        mf.add(mf1);
        mf.add(mf2);
        mf.add(mf3);
        mf.add(mf4);
        mf.addSeparator();
        mf.add(mf5);
        mf.add(mf6);
        mf.addSeparator();
        mf.add(mf7);


        mf1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane smd = new JOptionPane();
                smd.showMessageDialog(null, "Press Ok to open new page");

            }
        });

        final JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        JScrollPane scrl = new JScrollPane(jta);
        add(scrl);

        mf2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                int selection = chooser.showOpenDialog(DemoMenu.this);
                if (selection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "so u want to open the file...");
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    FileInputStream fis = null;
                    try {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        byte b[] = new byte[fis.available()];
                        fis.read(b);
                        String str = new String(b);
                        jta.setText(str);
                    } catch (Exception f) {
                        f.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            fis.close();
                        } catch (Exception exp) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mf3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            }
        });


        mf4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.showDialog(null, "Save As");
            }
        });

        mf7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane scd = new JOptionPane();
                scd.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you want to exit");
            }
        });
        me.add(me1);
        me.addSeparator();
        me.add(me2);
        me.add(me3);
        me.add(me4);
        me.add(me5);
        me.addSeparator();
        me.add(me6);
        me.add(me7);
        me.add(me8);
        me.add(me9);
        me.addSeparator();
        me.add(me10);
        me.add(me11);
        me11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Date d1 = new Date();
                JOptionPane smddate = new JOptionPane();
                smddate.showMessageDialog(null, d1);

            }
        });

        mfo.add(mfo1);
        mfo.add(mfo2);

        mv.add(mv1);

        mh.add(mh1);
        mh.addSeparator();
        mh.add(mh2);

        setSize(520, 540);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but a few suggestions as TODO/BNI 1) Start GUI on EDT 2) return a preferred size & pack. 3) Since this is Swing, use [`read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) - much safer file loading method for text. ;) 4) Change `} catch (Exception exp) {
                        }` to `} catch (Exception exp) { exp.printStackTrace(); // very important!
                        }`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your class extend JFrame and from that JFrame you create a new JFrame.
Remove the line Frame `frm=new Frame();`
and use `this` instead of `frm`